# move Youtube iframe between react components

Tags: javascript, video, iframe, reactjs, youtube

Here is my plan.
I have a Playlist component in react.
This playlist loops through a list of video and print a Video component for every video.

So here is my structure

```
<Playlist>
   <Video />
   <Video />
   <Video />
   ...
</Playlist>
```

I want now to have a youtube iframe player and everytime i click on a video component, the iframe should be moved inside the clicked video component and it should load a new video.

Loading a new video is pretty easy using youtube api and the video id.
But i'm trying to figure how to manage all the other stuff.

Should the youtube iframe be a react component too?
The youtube iframe api want the id of the iframe container to be declared, so how can i connect the api to the component

```
youtubePlayer = new YT.Player( HERE_GOES_THE_ID , {
    height: '390',
    width: '640',
    videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE'
});
```

Moreover, what is the best way to change the youtube component parent? How to move it from a video component to the other?

I'm really confused about all this.

Additional info: I'm using Redux to manage play/pause state between components.